# Mobile GCN 1 AMD GPU and DPM Bug

Tags: linux, freeze, gpu, amd-radeon, dual-gpu

First of all, have a nice day. So, I have a laptop with these specs:

i3-6006U CPU & Intel HD 520 iGPU + AMD Radeon R5 M330 dGPU & 8 GB Dual Channel RAM & 500 GB SATA3 SSD & Fedora Linux (but the issue occurs on all the Linux distributions)

My problem is that the dGPU I use is a Southern Islands (HAINAN) GCN 1 AMD GPU and it doesn't work without DPM disabled. Simply, when I try to run something from that GPU, the whole system freezes and I must shut my laptop down, otherwise nothing happens but a frozen screen. I have another laptop with another mobile GCN 1 GPU (it's also HAINAN) and when I tested it, I get the same issue too. Also, I heard from people who have a DESKTOP GCN 1 GPU that they don't have this DPM bug, so I assume it's an issue that happens on mobile GCN 1 GPUs. Also, the issue occurs on both radeon and amdgpu driver, so the issue isn't related to the kernel driver that's in use.

So, it is said that this bug didn't use to happen on kernel 5.4 and earlier and after kernel 5.4, we are supposed to disable DPM to be able to use the GPU (radeon.dpm=0 or amdgpu.dpm=0 depending on what kernel driver we're using) and yes, it works when DPM is disabled but naturally this leads to poor performance. I can't play any of the games I play, especially DXVK games. I'm currently using my iGPU for games and dGPU for basic things like photo editing, web browsing etc.

My question is, is there a way to fix this bug, I mean, is there a way to both keep DPM enabled and use the GPU without getting a system freeze and with a decent performance?

By the way, this link might help you to determine the issue better: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/kioq6p/comment/gx8841t/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

Thank you so much for reading, have a nice day!